# Post Id from facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using **Facebook graph API** to upload photo to the Facebook and on return I am getting the `object id` (which is actually the photo id), but I need the `POST ID` of that particular post in order to get the details such total number of comments and total number of likes of that post.

Is it possible to get the post Id using object id? Or is there any Facebook API to get the comments count and likes count using the object id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID` will return to you all the information (that you have permissions to see) for that photo object.

You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test these methods out...

Comment: @ Lix : thanks Lix , using the same id (Photo Id) i am unable to get only list of 'recent' comments and likes but not count of comments and count of likes and not even post id.

Comment: The photo_id itself **IS** the post.... A photo object can have comments and likes on it.  If you are only getting the recent results - notice that there should also be "next" and "previous" links in the response you get - you can make a call to those links to get more info.

Comment: but thats not what i want to do... it make my application slow if i count the comments from the response. If i am able to get the post id of it i can make use of another api to directly get the comments count instead of parsing and calculating count form the response.

Comment: Facebook will not return all of the comments for a specific object in one request.  This would make facebook "slow" (as you put it).  They paginate the response to spread out the traffic and lessen the load on their servers.  This is the correct method to retrieve information on a facebook object.

Comment: you could use https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID?fields=page_story_id which will return you the "post id" that you can then use to get the insights.